# Fastlane run spm does not find Package.swift

Tags: ios, fastlane, swift-package-manager

I have import my first Swift Package in my app.

Everything is compiling correctly and my package is well imported in my app.

But when i am executing `fastlane run spm` command, i have this error :

> error: Could not find Package.swift in this directory or any of its parent directories.

What did I missed ?